# Bootsnips "Simple Carousel" by ameenullah Will Not Work

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'mm trying to put a carousel into a page. I copied the code from [Bootsnips](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/simple-carousel) and the other solution for this same problem haven't worked.

My HTML Code is as follows:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
                <div id="Carousel" class="carousel slide">

                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#Carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#Carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#Carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                </ol>

                <!-- Carousel items -->
                <div class="carousel-inner">

                <div class="item active">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                      <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                      <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                      <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    </div><!--.row-->
                </div><!--.item-->

                <div class="item">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                        <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                        <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                        <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    </div><!--.row-->
                </div><!--.item-->

                <div class="item">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                        <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                        <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                        <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    </div><!--.row-->
                </div><!--.item-->

                </div><!--.carousel-inner-->
                  <a data-slide="prev" href="#Carousel" class="left carousel-control">‹</a>
                  <a data-slide="next" href="#Carousel" class="right carousel-control">›</a>
                </div><!--.Carousel-->

        </div>
    </div>
</div><!--.container-->
```

Then I place the CSS in which seems to work fine:

```
body{padding-top:20px;}
.carousel {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding: 0 40px 30px 40px;
}
/* The controlsy */
.carousel-control {
    left: -12px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #222222;
    border: 4px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 23px 23px 23px 23px;
    margin-top: 90px;
}
.carousel-control.right {
    right: -12px;
}
/* The indicators */
.carousel-indicators {
    right: 50%;
    top: auto;
    bottom: -10px;
    margin-right: -19px;
}
/* The colour of the indicators */
.carousel-indicators li {
    background: #cecece;
}
.carousel-indicators .active {
background: #428bca;
}
```

Then the Java script in as follows here:

```
<!-- Calling jquery first -->
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Carousel -->
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.carousel').carousel({
      interval: 3000
    })
  });    
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this as working carousel code as per your bootsnips link.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Carousel').carousel({
        interval: 5000
    })
});
```

```css
body{padding-top:20px;}
.carousel {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding: 0 40px 30px 40px;
}
/* The controlsy */
.carousel-control {
 left: -12px;
    height: 40px;
 width: 40px;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #222222;
    border: 4px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 23px 23px 23px 23px;
    margin-top: 90px;
}
.carousel-control.right {
 right: -12px;
}
/* The indicators */
.carousel-indicators {
 right: 50%;
 top: auto;
 bottom: -10px;
 margin-right: -19px;
}
/* The colour of the indicators */
.carousel-indicators li {
 background: #cecece;
}
.carousel-indicators .active {
background: #428bca;
}
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
                <div id="Carousel" class="carousel slide">
                 
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#Carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#Carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#Carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                </ol>
                 
                <!-- Carousel items -->
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    
                <div class="item active">
                 <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                   <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                   <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                   <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                 </div><!--.row-->
                </div><!--.item-->
                 
                <div class="item">
                 <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                  <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                  <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                  <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                 </div><!--.row-->
                </div><!--.item-->
                 
                <div class="item">
                 <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                  <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                  <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                  <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                 </div><!--.row-->
                </div><!--.item-->
                 
                </div><!--.carousel-inner-->
                  <a data-slide="prev" href="#Carousel" class="left carousel-control">‹</a>
                  <a data-slide="next" href="#Carousel" class="right carousel-control">›</a>
                </div><!--.Carousel-->
                 
  </div>
 </div>
</div><!--.container-->
```

Comment: That did the trick I see what I am doing wrong here. Thank I a little new to this.